# "Invisible" error while manipulating 2d array. (0 errors, 0 warnings)

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, transpose

App crashes but I can't see the reason. 
I've been examining the code for many times, but still there is a problem.

I have 2d array 'a'(NxM) and I have to transpose it. The new array is 'p'(MxN).

Here is part of program:

```
/// 7: Transposing array. ( NxM ---> MxN ).   
int **p = NULL;

p = (int **)malloc(M*sizeof(int *));

if ( NULL == p)
{
    printf("Failed to allocate memory.");
    return 1;
}

for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    p[i] = (int *)malloc(N*sizeof(int ));

// Filling in the new array called "p" with '0's.
for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        p[i][j] = 0;

// Transposing array.
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    for ( j = 0; j < M; j++ )
    {
        a[i][j] = p[j][i];
    }
}

// Displaying ARRAY
printf(">>>\n\n");
for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ )
{
    for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        printf("%4d ", p[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Tell me what is wrong, please.

UPDATE: I apologize for the mistake I've made..

```
// Filling in the new array called "p" with '0's.
for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        p[i][j] = 0;   // there will be 'p', not 'a'.
```

Comment: So where is `a` defined?

Comment: Are you still facing the issue with your updated code?

Comment: The current problem is solved. But now the last column of array contains trash. But everything is good when I write: `for ( j = 0; j <= N; j++ )`... Why does it so?  `j < N` must be right, but it doesn't..

Comment: @Genuine.Zealot I have just tried your code locally on `MinGW` / `gcc` and it works fine without any issues. I was able to transpose a rectangular array (5 x 7) and print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `a` is of size `N x M`, the issue is coming from this loop, where you are accessing `M x N` elements instead of `N x M`

```
// Filling in the new array called "p" with '0's.
for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        a[i][j] = 0;
```

This loop should have been

```
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) // M is swapped with N
    for ( j = 0; j < M; j++ ) // N is swapped with M
        a[i][j] = 0;
```

And, from your question, `a` is the input array which needs to be transposed to `p`. Hence, the processing step should have been

```
// Transposing array.
for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{ 
    for ( j = 0; j < M; j++ )
    {
        p[j][i] = a[i][j];
    }
}
```

With these changes, the code is working as expected. A sample code which prints data at different stages is uploaded at http://cfiddle.net/zoZazB

Comment: `for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ ) 
    for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        p[i][j] = 0;`_____
Why does `p[x][N-1] != 0`? (The last column contains trash) Any ideas?

Comment: @Genuine.Zealot.. I didn't get your question. Please find my code which is working uploaded as http://cfiddle.net/zoZazB. Are you still facing some issue?

Comment: Understood! I have to improve your logical thinking...
  Thanks! 

P.S. Nice site "cfiddle.net"!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here: since `a` is of `N *M`, but you accidently made it `M*N`.

```
 // Filling in the new array called "p" with '0's.
 //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^You are doing with a not p below
 for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
         a[i][j] = 0;
 //here it seems that a is of M*N not N*M
 //your comment and code does not match
```

size mismatch will cause you to access memory that does not belong to `a`, therefore, crash.